# What event callback in the DOM API can I call when a form field receives focus (either through mouse click or by tabbing)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

My goal is to make form fields bigger when the cursor focuses on them either through a mouseclick or by tabbing using the keyboard.

Using document.activeElement focus I could know when user click inside text
input or when the user clicks on a select element.

My problem is when user is using tab key and moving their way to select list.
While using the keyboard only and not using mouse , if user will press tab and get to select list element focus event will not fire and select will not be resized.

What event will determine if cursor is located on select element while pressing tab key only?

Comment: Use CSS `:focus` pseudoclass.

Answer (score 0):

With only using vanilla javascript you can easily select the input field you are trying to make bigger by using the function `querySelector` from the document object given to you. Then by adding an `eventListener` to that reference and watching only for 'focus' events. These would be called regardless of how your user got to that component / field. By Tab key or by mouseclick.

Here is a short example taken from the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/focus_event#:%7E:text=The%20focus%20event%20fires%20when,opposite%20of%20focus%20is%20blur%20.).

```
   //HTML
    
    <form id="form">
      <input type="text" placeholder="text input">
    </form>
    
    //JavaScript
    
    const textInstance = document.querySelector('input[type="text"]');
  
    textInstance .addEventListener('focus', (event) => {
// inside here you can change the style using CSS, i.e. make field bigger. In this case it sets the field background pink.
      event.target.style.background = 'pink';    
    });
```